# Find & Replace to retain only middle term of three

Tags: regex, replace, openoffice-calc

`data1/data2/data3`

How can I find and replace all cells with this format to only result in:

`data2`

Always the MIDDLE term stays.

Comment: "Difficult" is a noise word - it means nothing. By definition, by asking your question, you *do not know* how difficult the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a search/replace, with `Regular Expressions" selected (see <kbd>More Options...</kbd>) with this regex in the search box:

```
^.*/(\<[:alnum:]*\>)/.*$
```

and this as replacement:

```
$1
```

This assumes that there are only three "dataX" parts in every cell. If a cell contains data1/data2/data3/data4, its content will be replaced by data3. not data2-

[image]